# ImportJson() print the data only when I return the function in Google App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to implement a Loop on `ImportJson()` but it doesn't work without return

The Code from this github link :[ImportJson Into Google Sheets](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164)
I made a new function

**This's Work but it prints only 1 API call for sure because of return**

```
function ImportData1() {

  veunueid_arr = ["KovZpZA7AAEA", "KovZpa2gne"];



  for (var Veunue_id1 = 0; Veunue_id1 < 2; Veunue_id1++) {

    var url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?venueId= " + veunueid_arr[Veunue_id1] + "&apikey=" + API_key + "&locale=*";


    //  console.log("Veuneid" + Veunue_id + Venue_Id_List.length);
    console.log("ImportData1();" + Venue_Id_List.length);

     return ImportJSON (url, "/_embedded/events/name", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders" );

     
  }
 

}
```

**This's doesn't work** because I didn't use `return`!
***So It should print the data even without Return but it doesn't***

```
function ImportData1() {
    
      veunueid_arr = ["KovZpZA7AAEA", "KovZpa2gne"];
    
    
    
      for (var Veunue_id1 = 0; Veunue_id1 < 2; Veunue_id1++) {
    
        var url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?venueId= " + veunueid_arr[Veunue_id1] + "&apikey=" + API_key + "&locale=*";
 
    
        //  console.log("Veuneid" + Veunue_id + Venue_Id_List.length);
        console.log("ImportData1();" + Venue_Id_List.length);
    
          ImportJSON (url, "/_embedded/events/name", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders" );
    
         
      }
     
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to join results from several urls in one big list.
You can use Array.concat, like this

```
function ImportData1() {    
  veunueid_arr = ["KovZpZA7AAEA", "KovZpa2gne"];
  var results = [];    
    
  for (var Veunue_id1 = 0; Veunue_id1 < 2; Veunue_id1++) {   
    var url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?venueId= " + veunueid_arr[Veunue_id1] + "&apikey=" + API_key + "&locale=*";
 
    results = results.concat(ImportJSON(url, "/_embedded/events/name", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders" ));             
  }    
 return results;
}
```

Comment: It's not working as well, The problem is the sheet updates values only when `return ImportJson()` It should be working normally because I'm calling `ImportJson()` which return something inside as well.

Comment: Well, I need to see how you process other code for suggestions, probably you just need to pull some key from result json.

Comment: This's the full code: https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

Comment: May I ask how to change `/_embedded/events/name` Path to something like Event_Name 
Also when it concatenate it Prints  `/_embedded/events/name` not as a one list

Comment: It works I thought I added a comment between these comments. Thanks.